# FIND function in VBA - Object does not support this property or Method

Tags: excel, vba

Unable to run FIND function in one sheet.

I want to find some cell value the selected range and color it.
I am getting error as

> Object doesn't support this property or method

```vb
Sub coloring()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VNF Placement").Activate

    Dim rg As Range

    Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VNF Placement").Range("B11:CV500")
    lrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VNF Placement").Cells(Rows.count, 105).End(xlUp).Row

    g = 3   'colour index
    i = 1

    For i = 2 To lrow
       For Each c In rg
           If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VNF Placement").Find(Cells(i, 105), xlValues) Then
               c.Interior.ColorIndex = g
           End If
       Next

       g = g + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory. A `Worksheet` does not have a method called `Find`.

Comment: Why are you looping within another loop? The second loop has no use at all

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VNF Placement").Find(Cells(i, 105), xlValues)` is not an assertion, it returns a range or nothing

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `Like`, that's to compare values. `Find` is a Range object that returns the range of the found value. Plus, you need to specify a range for Find to look in.

For example:

```
Dim rslt As Range, i As Long, lrow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("VNF Placement")

    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lrow
        Set rslt = .Range("A:A").Find(.Cells(i, 105), Lookat:=xlPart)
        If not rslt Is Nothing Then 
            MsgBox "The address of '" & .Cells(i, 105).Value & "' is '" & rslt.Address & "'", vbInformation
        End If
    Next

End With
```

Comment: Please see above I have written the complete code. In one of the versions of my project it is working fine. But not in this sheet.

Comment: @Ninja Your code could not work in any version of a project. A `Worksheet` does not have a method called `Find`, you cannot change that. The code you have in the question will never work.

Comment: @Ninja glad you got it working! If my answer helped you, please accept it :)

Comment: In that case you could answer your own question for future reference, but that's entirely optional